# $Lookup Foriegn Field Mongoose: Unknown Argument

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I am trying to use aggregate to replace populate in my code. I am displaying all posts with media as the path to media file.

My Post Model look like this

```
const { model, Schema, Types } = require("mongoose");

const postSchema = new Schema(
  {
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    views: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    user: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "user",
    },
    media: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "media",
      required: false,
    },
    comments: [
      {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "comment",
      },
    ],
    // 1 lakh comments
    // comment ma pagination
    // total_comment = 100000
    likes: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "user" }],
  },
  {
    timestamps: { createdAt: "created_at", updatedAt: "updated_at" },
  }
);

postSchema.methods.isOwner = function ({ _id, is_admin }) {
  return is_admin || this.user.equals(_id);
};

module.exports = new model("post", postSchema);
```

Doing so for GET route /all. Which should return all the posts.
But I am getting this error.
[image]

My controller looks like this

```
router.get("/all", async (req, res, next) => {
    await postModel
      .aggregate([
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "media",
            localField: "media",
            foriegnField: "_id",
            as: "media",
          },
        },
        { $unwind: "$media" },
        {
          $addFields: {
            totalLikes: { $size: "$likes" },
            totalComments: { $size: "$comments" },
          },
        },
        {
          $project: {
            likes: 0,
            comments: 0,
          },
        },
      ])
      .then((allPosts) => {
        res.status(200).send(allPosts);
      });
  })
```

In browser the output without $lookup looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo mistake in your keyname `foriegnField`.

```
$lookup: {
   from: "media",
   localField: "media",
   foreignField: "_id",
   as: "media",
},
```